# Where statement for exact match on Many to Many SQL tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to construct a SQL statement to search in two tables that are in a many to many relation.

**Problem** : SQL statement to search for products with exact stones.

For example, in the below tables, I need a statement that will search for product with Ruby and Emerald stone ONLY. In all my attempts I get both Ring and Necklace because they both have Ruby and Emerald even though Necklace has one additional stone. It should only give Ring product.

I need a way to implement the AND operator on the stone table so that the result contains products that have the exact stones. Please help.

**Table stone**

| s_id | s_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ruby |
| 2 | Emerald |
| 3 | Onyx |

**Table product**

| p_id | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ring |
| 2 | Necklace |
| 3 | Pendent |

**Relation table - product_stone**

| p_s_id | p_id | s_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [relational division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question. We need to find the cross join of the two tables "divided" by our list, with no remainder i.e. no other `stone` in `product`.

We will assume that p_id and s_id are unique:

```sql
;WITH StonesToFind AS (    -- we could also use a table variable etc here
    SELECT *
    FROM stone
    WHERE s_name IN ('Ruby','Emerald')
)
SELECT p.p_name
FROM product AS p    -- let's get all products...
JOIN product_stone AS ps ON ps.p_id = p.p_id   -- ...cross join all their stones
LEFT JOIN StonesToFind AS s ON s.s_id = ps.s_id    -- they may have stones in the list
GROUP BY p.p_id, p_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN s.s_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
-- the number of non matching stones in product must be zero
    AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StonesToFind);
-- the total number of stones must be the same as the list
```